# How to keep the date range with time range picker open after setting the dates?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using `ngx-bootstrap` to display a date and time range pickers. However, when selecting the date ranges, the picker closes. How can I keep it open until time ranges are selected?

```html
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  #daterangepicker="bsDaterangepicker"
  [ngModel]="calendardDate"
  bsDaterangepicker
  [outsideClick]="true"
  [bsConfig]="{
    containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue',
    rangeInputFormat: 'DD/MM, h:mm a',
    dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM, h:mm a',
    showWeekNumbers: false,
    maxDateRange: 60,
    withTimepicker: true,
    keepDatepickerOpened: true,
    keepDatesOutOfRules: true,
    isAnimated:true
    }"
  (bsValueChange)="changeCalendarDate($event,false,daterangepicker)"
  (click)="clickDatePicker(daterangepicker)"
/>
```

```
angular 15
ngx-boostrap 10.3.0
```

Answer (score -1):

From version ngx-bootstrap 10 you can use:

```
[bsConfig]="{ withTimepicker: true, keepDatepickerOpened: true}
```

> If you use datepicker with timepicker together, you are able to set keepDatepickerOpened config option and keep datepicker opened until date isn't changed

See there documentation here:

[Close behavior with timepicker changes](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker#close-behavior)

Comment: this does not work

Comment: Indeed it doesn't